# Add a loading gif in button or in the whole form when u click submit form

Tags: javascript, php

Well i have a form and when u Submit it it redirects to another page,i would like to add a loader or something when u click the submit button,any help?

```
<form method="post" action="service.php" id="leadbox-form">
<div class="form-row stageButton">
<div class="col-md-12">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn_form btn-block" id="btnSubmit"name="btnSubmit" val="GET STARTED NOW"/>
</div>
```